# dispatch method in view for parent child composition

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elm-architecture, elmish

I am trying to understand the way fable is supposed to work with parent child composition. Things are quite easy when it comes to `update` method, `init`, and the definition of commands. But the `view` method and its `dispatch` method are tricky to find out

In my code, the child is:

```
module DeploymentView

type DeploymentTypeView =
    | DeployContainerView

type Model = { 
 CurrentView : DeploymentTypeView option
}

type Msg =
| ShowDeployContainer

let init () : Model =
    let initialModel = { 
        CurrentView = None
    }
    initialModel


let update (msg : Msg) (currentModel : Model) : Model * Cmd<Msg> = 
    match msg with 
    | ShowDeployContainer ->
        let nextModel = { 
            currentModel with CurrentView = Some DeployContainerView 
        }
        nextModel, Cmd.none     
    | _ -> currentModel, Cmd.none


let view (model : Model) (dispatch : Msg -> unit) =
    [
        Content.content [ Content.Modifiers [ Modifier.TextAlignment (Screen.All, TextAlignment.Left) ] ]
            [ 
                Heading.h3 [] [ str ("Deployments: ") ] 
            ] 

        Columns.columns []
            [ 
                Column.column [] [ button "deploy container" (fun _ -> dispatch ShowDeployContainer) ]
            ] 
    ]
```

And following this [documentation](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/parent-child.html) about parent child processing  I have define a parent like this one:

```
module Client

type PortalView =
| DeploymentView of DeploymentView.Model
| ProductAdministrationView


type Model = { 
    CurrentPortal : PortalView option
}

// The Msg type defines what events/actions can occur while the application is running
// the state of the application changes *only* in reaction to these events
type Msg =
| ShowDeployment
| ShowAdministration
| DeployContainerView of DeploymentView.Msg


// defines the initial state and initial command (= side-effect) of the application
let init () : Model * Cmd<Msg> =
    let initialModel = { 
        CurrentPortal = None 
    }
    initialModel, Cmd.none

let update (msg : Msg) (currentModel : Model) : Model * Cmd<Msg> =
    match  msg with
    | ShowDeployment ->
        let nextModel = { 
            currentModel with CurrentPortal = Some <| DeploymentView(DeploymentView.init())
        }
        nextModel, Cmd.none
    | ShowAdministration ->
        let nextModel = { 
            currentModel with CurrentPortal = Some ProductAdministrationView
        }
        nextModel, Cmd.none
    | DeployContainerView msg' ->
        let res, cmd = 
            match currentModel.CurrentPortal with
            | Some(DeploymentView(m)) -> DeploymentView.update msg' m
            | _ -> DeploymentView.init(), Cmd.none
        { currentModel with CurrentPortal = Some(DeploymentView(res)) }, Cmd.map DeployContainerView cmd
```

So far so good, my issue comes when it goes to the rendering of the view itself.
The client view uses a function as follows:

```
let view (model : Model) (dispatch : Msg -> unit)
```

where `Msg` is of type `DeploymentView.Msg`  whereas in the parent view I have access to a dispatch of type `Client.Msg -> unit`. how can I decompose the parent dispatch to map it to the child dispatch signature?

Comment: One thing that might help is to clone https://github.com/MangelMaxime/fulma-demo and spend some time browsing through it in VS Code + Ionide (or your preferred F# editor). It will take a little while to wrap your head around the application structure used in that demo, but once you understand it, you could do worse than to follow a similar structure in your own code.

Comment: There's good explanation of scaling Elmish applications here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Oc4xJivY78

Comment: @rmunn thanks for the link , that might exactly be the thing I was looking for... :)

Comment: @DaveShaw looks good, I'll watch it this week end.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily create a dispatch function that conforms to what the child expects by using the `>>` operator:

```fsharp
DeploymentView.view deploymentViewModel (DeployContainerView >> dispatch)
```

which is equivalent to doing:

```fsharp
DeploymentView.view deploymentViewModel (fun msg -> msg |> DeployContainerView |> dispatch)
```

That is, it wraps the child's message in `DeployContainerView`, then passes that to `dispatch`.

On another note, it is a common and good convention to use a `Msg` suffix on constructors used to wrap child `msg` types. You may want to consider renaming `DeployContainerView` to `DeploymentContainerMsg`.